# How to filter data on list based on user input in angular6?

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my html

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control pl-0" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">

<li>
                          <a href="#" ><i class="fal fa-suitcase"></i> UI Elements <i class="fal fa-angle-right float-right menu-arrow"></i></a>
                          <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Charts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tabs</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
```

In the above html i have list of elements, when user enter data on input field more than 2 characters then filter list data using angular6

Comment: Use [Pipe](https://codeburst.io/create-a-search-pipe-to-dynamically-filter-results-with-angular-4-21fd3a5bec5c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `li` tag to an array and then filter it:

```
data = ['Forms', 'Charts', 'Buttons', 'Tabs'];
filteredData: any[];
ngOnInit(){
  this.filteredData = this.data;
}
```

In your html view:

```
<ul class="sub-menu" *ngFor="let item of filteredData">
    <li><a href="#">{{item}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now fire event each time user type inside the input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control pl-0" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" (change)="filter($event)">
```

Inside your component:

```
filter($event){
  let reg = $event.target.value;
  this.filteredData = this.data.filter(x => return x.toLowerCase().indexOf(reg.toLowerCase()) != -1);
}
```

And the list will automatically change with the new filtered data.

Comment: If user input is going to call any api, then its not the ideal way to do it.

Comment: @ShadabFaiz of course working with api is something else.